# How do I create a Mac installer for my Java application?

Tags: java, macos, installation

I have created an executable JAR file for my Java application. If I double-click then it works fine. But I want to create installer for Mac OS, because I cannot give a JAR file to my users. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you give a JAR file to your users? Seems like with a custom icon it'd work just dandily.

Comment: My user is non technical. And also i want to create proper setup as other software does.

Comment: What's improper or technical about double-clicking a JAR file?

Comment: it does not have shortcut icon. also it does not make entry in registry file. It doesnot provide auro startup. User must click on an icon. that is not actual java program. but my jar will start working

Comment: So why not fix the app instead of making your users go through the hoops of an installer?

Comment: What if you cannot assume they will have Java installed? For Windows I can bundle in the jre. That would be a good reason to want an installer. Also a libs folder is ugly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, all you have to do here is to create a beautiful icon for your app, bundle it to your jar file to make it look more sophisticated, instead of using the default coffee cup icon.

Here is how you can do it:

http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java/

Please read the sessions starting from session 7.

Mac has java by default. And if your users are not technical, it makes no different for them if they are using a mac .exe or not, right?

Comment: Especially because Macs don't run `.exe`s. :P

Comment: **Heads up for 2015**:  The way to create a Mac installer for Java applications has changed significantly with Java 8 and Yosemite.  The instructions at the link above have been updated to use the new `javapackager` tool.  The old *JarBundler* and *AppBundler* approaches will become obsolete.

Comment: **Heads up for 2022:** The tooling has again changed significantly.  The new way is to use `jpackage` which is included in _openjdk._

Answer (score 5):

Just a comment to clear some of this up. Mac applications normally dont have installers. At all. They dont have a registry and normally you just drag the icon (which is actually a folder with the executables in a specific folder structure) into the applications folder. Thats it. Thats why if you have an executable with a nice icon and you put it in a .dmg image file nobody is gonna know the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree that a jar should be sufficent; but maybe you want to check [this (ClickInstall MacOSX 1.0.2)](http://wareseeker.com/Business-Finance/clickinstall-macosx-1.0.2.zip/7ce066d60) Installer Build Tool for OSX.

Answer (score 0):

The *very first* hit on Google for "Mac Installer" is the [Wikipedia article about the Mac Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installer_(Mac_OS_X)).

You can click through from there to read Apple's [Software Delivery Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SoftwareDistribution/Introduction/Introduction.html). It tells you in exhaustive detail everything you could possibly want to know about this.

Please, for your own good, read up on [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). You'll get much better results that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try jarbundler from http://informagen.com/JarBundler/.
You can create a nice OSX app including icon with it.
Just ship that. The user can drag this app to Application. No explicit installation step 
necessary.

I use this for my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is what you looking for, [How to Create a Mac Installer for Java Application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vw7lCrdFHFU)
give a try, many could help.

Comment: Note that this is a link to (an on-topic and useful) YouTube video.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: https://github.com/Jorl17/jar2app

For any changes made in code, I just need to move updated jar file in the folder application.app/Content/Java