# Automatically creating desktop icon for Java app launched by sh-script. MacOS

Tags: java, bash, macos, icons

I have a **sh-script** in MacOS that launches my application. I can use Automator to create executable desctop icon for it but manually.

Is there any way **automatically create a desktop icon** that will execute this sh-script by double-clicking on this icon? And also I would like to create such icon **using some parameters** like a path to custom image of the icon.

**Note**. In our project we have a number of jar-files for about 100Mb. So now I use sh-script with configuration to launch the application.

Comment: Are you asking how to create an **installer** for a java application? Like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536190/how-do-i-create-a-mac-installer-for-my-java-application ??? Icons are Icons, not programs. Your question is pretty unclear ...

Comment: At this point I don't need an installer. Just tie sh-script with desktop icon, not manually. Answer about creating app folder might be the right one, I'll try.

Comment: The answer with the ".command" extension is the simplest.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I know how to execute sh-script by double-clicking. The question is how to *automatically* create the executable desktop icon for sh-script.

Comment: `echo java -whatever foo bar > ~/Desktop/foo.command`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an app folder for your application and put the icon you want in it.

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. It might be very good solution. I would like to ask: in our application we have a lot of jar-files so is it possible to put sh-script in such folder?

Comment: @KirillCh Yes. You MUST include a launcher somewhere in the structure. There is a binary version that comes with MacOs, but there is an open-source alternative that is a shell script: https://github.com/tofi86/universalJavaApplicationStub